# Does `this.SomeMethod` passed as Func argument capture `this`?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, capture, func

If a method asks for some `Func`:

```
void Foo(Func<string> stringFactory);
```

Then passing a lambda referencing `this` introduces variable capturing:

```
Foo(() => this.MagicStringProperty); // Captures `this`
```

Does this happen also when passing an instance method instead of a lambda?

```
Foo(this.GetMagicString); // Capturing??

string GetMagicString()
{
    return "Bar";
}
```

If so, is this compiled to a similar thing as the lambda version?

If not, how does it manage to pass both the method (which exists somewhere) and the instance (which exists somewhere else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't have to be captured in a closure here. The difference between the calls is that there is a compiler generated method for `() => this.MagicStringProperty()`. This method simply calls `this.GetMagicString()`.

If you decompile the code you will see that `Foo(this.GetMagicString)` translates to `this.Foo(new Func<string>((object) this, __methodptr(GetMagicString)))` and that `Foo(() => this.GetMagicString())` translates to `this.Foo(new Func<string>((object) this, __methodptr(<.ctor>b__1_0)))` where `<.ctor>b__1_0` is the compiler generated method that calls `this.GetMagicString()`:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private string <.ctor>b__1_0()
{
  return this.GetMagicString();
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, a `Func` is constructed that holds both the reference to `this` and the reference to the method? And does this also mean that every call will perform an allocation, `new Func<string>(...)`?

Comment: @Timo: Yes and Yes.

Comment: Thank you. That's actually fairly disappointing. I wonder if they could not have easily done this with a struct...